# How to know recently updated files

Tags: linux, files, monitoring, io

If I run iostat -x 1 I saw ocassionally large 5MB to 10MB writes.

What files are being written?

I want to check the recently created files with size over 5MB for example.

How would I do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Find file modified within X minute under /path

```
find /path -cmin -X

Sign before minute:
    + more than X minutes / over X minutes
    - less than X minutes / within X minutes
   (no sign) exact
```

Example: find all files in /var/log (including sub-dir) modified within last 30min

```
find /var/log -cmin -30
```

### Find file with size bigger X under /path

```
find /path -size +X<unit>

Sign before size:
    + larger than
    - less than
   (no sign) exact

<unit> :
    b = block (default,512byte)
    c = byte
    w = word (2-byte)
    k = kbyte
    M = Mbyte
    G = Gbyte
```

Example: find all files in /var/log (including sub-dir) bigger than 50k

```
find /var/log -size +50k
```

### Combine

Example: find all files in /var/log (including sub-dir) bigger than 50k modified within last 30min

```
find /var/log -cmin -30 -size +50k
```

If you want to **include 50k** in your result, change to

```
find /var/log -cmin -30 -size +49k
```

**PS**: Avoid doing `find / .....` as not only it will take a long time, it also include directories(/dev, /sys, /proc, ...) generally not suitable for search.

Comment: John, -cmin 30 will find files EXACTLY changed 30 minutes ago.  You're after -cmin -30 (30 minutes or newer).

Comment: @tink Thank you, corrected. I remember to put it in the general line but forget to put it in examples.

Comment: you could only check the files that `lsof | grep /` will display at the same time the io is showing a big write

Comment: Do you really mean `-cmin` instead of `-mmin`?

Answer (score 1):

With `find` you have to actively search for files on the file system and trust their time stamps.

The altenative on a recent linux system is [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). In that case the kernel watches for file system changes as they happen and you can query them for example with `inotifywait -m`.
That should give you a good idea what is going on in real time.

The inotify approach does not work well when recursively monitoring large directory trees. In that case `find` will give you an idea what directories to monitor.